# How non-blocking loop {while( QMutex::trylock() );} works?

Tags: qt, loops, nonblocking

In Qt documentation about `QMutex` it is said:

> (...) When you call lock() in a thread, other threads that try to call lock() in the same place will block until the thread that got the lock calls unlock(). A non-blocking alternative to lock() is tryLock(). (...)

I have been using this code many times:

```
QMutex mutex;<br>
while( !mutex.tryLock() );
```

Can someone explain me how this `tryLock()` method is built that `while()` loop won't hang whole program?

Two threads shares one `QMutex` and act as a communication FIFO - when one thread is sending data, and another data is scheduled to the second thread, that thread is waiting for the first thread to complete. Communication comply with Modbus standard - send1-receive1, send2-receive2.

You cannot make parallel send and receive. So always one thread is active, the rest is waiting.

```
QMutex mutex; 
thread1() { 
    while( !mutex.tryLock() )
        ; 
    doThread1Job(); 
} 

thread2() { 
    while( !mutex.tryLock() )
        ; 
    doThread2Job(); 
}
```

Comment: You're spinning on that tryLock, why would you want to do that?

Comment: I'm waiting for the thread to finish - after that other code executes.

Comment: You could make a function which checks the lock, if it's locked, schedule another call to this function in the future (into the main event loop) and returns. If it's not locked, do your business and return.

Comment: @killdaclick: why not just lock if you want to wait?

Comment: @Mat it works like this:
Two threads shares one QMutex and act as a communication FIFO - when one thread is sending data, and another data is scheduled to the second thread, that thread is waiting for the first thread to complete. Communication comply with Modbus standard - send1-receive1, send2-receive2. You cannot make parallel send and receive. So always one thread is active, the rest is waiting.
    QMutex mutex;
    thread1()
    {
      while( !mutex.tryLock() );
      doThread1Job();
    }

    thread2()
    {
      while( !mutex.tryLock() );
      doThread2Job();
    }

Comment: I repeat my question: why don't you simply lock/unlock?

Comment: What Mat means is that `mutex.lock()` and `while( !mutex.tryLock() );` effectively do the same thing: Wait till the lock is aquired

Comment: @Mat & TimMeyer
Ok I see your point. I misunderstood the documentation. Both lock() and tryLock() wait until the lock is released. So I assume this way of waiting is achieved int the way "Styne666" described?

Comment: `tryLock` doesn't wait, that's the whole point of that function. If you want to wait on a lock, you `lock`. `tryLock` is if you want to lock _only if the lock isn't already locked.

Comment: If you want it non-blocking, consider sending a (queued) signal from the secondary thread.

Comment: If one thread is blocked while the other one works, you don't need 2 threads in the first place.

Comment: @killdaclick Just for completeness: You did not misunderstand the documentation: `tryLock()` on its own does not wait until the lock is released. However, `while( !mutex.tryLock() );` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're spinning on `tryLock()` in the GUI thread, then of course it will block your user interface. A `tryLock()` does not spin an event loop or anything like that. In your case, the `tryLock()` loop is same as just calling `lock()`.

The non-blocking alternative to `tryLock()` should be used as follows: if it fails, you wait and try again. You set up a `singleShot` QTimer to fire your retry slot.

In any case, it'd probably be easier to send a Qt signal to the waiting thread from the working thread, instead of implementing your own means of synchronization.